# Highchart solidgauge is arc clipping but pane is coming correctly

Tags: highcharts, visualization, gauge, react-highcharts, solid

[image]

This is mainly happening when startAngle > 90 and endAngle < 270 (this makes arc in bottom) and difference of angle is around 50 (It like quarter arc having start and end angle in bottom).
This can be fixed If I reduce Y direction from top value.
I want to know why this is happening at first place. Only arc is cropping but Pane is coming correctly.

```
pane: {
        startAngle: +this.gaugeSetting.minAngle,
        endAngle: +this.gaugeSetting.maxAngle,
        center: [`${this.gaugeSetting.centerX}%`,`${this.gaugeSetting.centerY}%`],
        background: this.gaugeSetting.show ? paneData : [],
        // size: this.gaugeSetting.shapeType === "CUSTOM" ? this.gaugeSetting.customChartSize+"%" : this.gaugeSetting.chartSize,
        size:'100%'
      },
```

Comment: Do let me know if you guys want any other code references.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in an online editor: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a8hunkwo/?

Comment: @Michał make endAngle of pane to 180

Comment: @Michał https://jsfiddle.net/4m78o3x9/3/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highchart soligauge is clipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76825028/highchart-soligauge-is-clipping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/8951377/ppotaczek
for answering this

"It looks like a Highcharts regression bug (working fine with v8: jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cf5xroum). Could you report it on the Highcharts GitHub repository: github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues ? As a workaround, you can disable series animation or call chart.reflow after it. Example: jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r3uv97pk "

I degraded the version of highchart to 8.1.0 then it is working.