# Highchart soligauge is clipping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have this link over at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4m78o3x9/3/) .
My solid gauge is clipping when I set the startAngle to 90 and endAngle to 180.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
  },
  pane: {
    startAngle: 90,
    endAngle: 180,
    background: [{
      outerRadius: '112%',
      innerRadius: '88%',
      backgroundColor: Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0])
        .setOpacity(0.3)
        .get(),
      borderWidth: 0
    }, {
      outerRadius: '87%',
      innerRadius: '63%',
      backgroundColor: Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0])
        .setOpacity(0.3)
        .get(),
      borderWidth: 0
    }, {
      outerRadius: '62%',
      innerRadius: '38%',
      backgroundColor: Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0])
        .setOpacity(0.3)
        .get(),
      borderWidth: 0
    }]
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickPositions: []
  },
  plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      linecap: 'round',
      stickyTracking: false,
      rounded: true
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [{
      radius: '112%',
      innerRadius: '88%',
      y: 80
    }]
  }, {
    data: [{
      radius: '87%',
      innerRadius: '63%',
      y: 65
    }]
  }, {
    data: [{
      radius: '62%',
      innerRadius: '38%',
      y: 50
    }]
  }]
});
```

If I give center property to pane with value of x to 50% and y to 10% then it is coming correctly.

Comment: Hi @Anuj Shaan, It looks like a Highcharts regression bug (working fine with v8: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cf5xroum/). Could you report it on the Highcharts GitHub repository: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues ? As a workaround, you can disable series animation or call `chart.reflow` after it. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r3uv97pk/